# d3 x axis too short for scatterplot content

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I'm having trouble with my X axis width on a D3 scatterplot - what's happening is that my x-axis isn't filling the space allotted, that the Data happily fill. JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u4cGJ/

I've defined my d3 scale's output range thusly:

```
.range([padding, svgWidth - padding]);
```

and the output range of points on the scatterplot perfectly lines up with this, but the x-axis doesn't - it stops short of the range of points displayed, - it's doing exactly what I tell it to do, and yet, as the svg extends farther out, the data fill in that space too, leaving a section of data that are visible, but not being placed in context of an axis.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Actually, I've realized the problem is somewhat different than I had imagined. What I'm experiencing is that data that exceeds my defined output range is shown, beyond where my axis reaches. The axis is doing exactly what I tell it to do (my padding value was simply higher than I thought) - the issue I want to solve is how to have the data and the axis output width line up with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the problem is that your defined domain doesn't include the full extent of your data. The scale domain/range are used to map ranges of data values so that if your domain is [0,10] and your range is [0,100], you will get values like range(0) = 0, range(1) = 10, range(2) = 20... range(10) = 100 (depending on the kind of scale used).

Since it's just mapping domain to range, if you give it a value that it can't map, you aren't likely to get a value inside of your range's extent. Eg. if you do range(11) you won't get a value between 0 and 100. Since the range value is what your axis and plot are likely using to build the actual svg, the points that fall outside of your domain are going to end up off your plot (or NaN or something).

Try deriving the domain from the data itself. D3 has min, max, and extent functions to make this easy for you. If you have an array of point objects, you can use the accessor as a function to provide the right value to use in the calculation.

Here's an example:

```
var data =  [{x:1, y:1}, {x:2, y:4}, {x:3, y:2}, {x:4, y:1}, {x:5, y:2}];
var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; });
var yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; });
```

See the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/c9qw8/

Looking at your fiddle, it looks like there's an error in the logic where you're using the wrong domain for what's actually being plotted. If you get rid of the default min and max stuff, it seems to correct the problem you're describing:

```
function makeScales(xAxisRepresents, domainMinOverride, domainMaxOverride) {
   var domainMin = d3.min(dataset, function datumToValueTransformer(datum) { return datum[xAxisRepresents]; });
   var domainMax = d3.max(dataset, function datumToValueTransformer(datum) { return datum[xAxisRepresents]; });
```

Comment: I think you've analyzed the problem correctly, but it doesn't fix what I'm dealing with, because those limited domains were intentional; I'm trying to figure out how to best display my data without the outliers causing the scale to be completely unreadable. However, given your analysis, I think the best way to fix this would be to solve the data-lining-up problem using what you suggest, and solve the outliers problem by filtering the initial dataset, rather than simply the domain. I'll see if that works!

Comment: That's generally how I deal with it (filter the data). But, you can also create a clip path to "hide" everything that's off the chart area itself. That's what is done in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 . If you inspect the dom, you'll see that when you are zoomed, the chart it just stretched with a clip to hide the stuff that extends beyond the edges of the visible area.